# How to write the equation to represent the cost function in python?

Tags: python

Hi there~ I am trying to solve a problem about linear prediction in python. I got a dataset which is a sequence, has around 500 values.

I need to predict x(n) with 2 of its previous samples x(n-1) and x(n-2) as: x(n)=a1*x(n-1)+a2*x(n-2)
The cost function is J= sum((x(n)-a1*x(n-1)-a2*x(n-2)),2).
actually I need to use gradient descent method to find the best a1 and a2 to minimize the J. I don't know how to write the expression to represent the x(n-1) and x(n-2) since their in the list and only has one column.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

with open('datafile-02.txt','r') as n:

     n=n.readlines()

     def PE(a1,a2,x,n):

         return sum(np.power((- a1*n[:,0] - a2*n[:,1]+x),2))

     a1=1
     a2=-1
     x=0

     alpha=0.005
     max_no_of_iter=5000

     rec_J=np.zeros(max_no_of_iter)
     rec_abc=np.zeros([max_no_of_iter,3])

     J=PE(a1,a2,x,n)
     rec_J[0]=J
     rec_abc[0,:]=[a1,a2,x]

     for i in range(1,max_no_of_iter):
         tmp=(x + a1*n[:,0]*-1 + a2*n[:,1]*-1)


         a1-=2*alpha*sum(n[0]*n[1]*a2+n[0]**2*a1-x*n[0])
         a2-=2*alpha*sum(n[0]*n[1]*a1-x*n[1]+n[1]**2*a2)
         x-=alpha*sum(tmp)

     J=PE(a1,a2,x,n)    

     print('After iter'+str(i+1)+',Cost J is '+str(J)+'for [a1,a2,x] ='+str([a1,a2,x]))
```

Comment: Couldnt you put all of the lines from the text file in an array?

Comment: I'd say cost is something like ` x[ 2 : : ] - a1 * x[ 1 : -1 : ] - a2 * x[ : -2 : ]` ... probably squared and then summed

Comment: Anyhow, I don't think you have to evaluate the cost function, as you just need the gradient to vanish....well as a sanity check, I guess. OK

Comment: Seems like the [:,0] is for 2D array and my dataset is just a list, I don't know how to write the expression of selected (n-1) or (n-2) data in the list

Comment: Thank you all of you! It seems that I know how to present the equation, but now I got a new error, which is    ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U22'), dtype('<U22')) -> dtype('<U22')   How should I solve it?